# Azure dependency conflict with Jackson: java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions

Tags: java, azure, jackson, conflict, linkageerror

I'm having troubles with introducing azure storage sdk into my Java project. There apparently are conflicts between various Jackson dependencies versions, but the odd thing is that all the dependencies being imported are of the same, up-to-date version.

The azure dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

The code that triggers the problem:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .buildClient();
blobServiceClient.createBlobContainer("hello-world-" + UUID.randomUUID());
```

The problem:

```
ERROR [com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim] (reactor-http-nio-1) Package versions: jackson-core=2.12.6, jackson-databind=2.12.6-1, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.15.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.12.6, azure-core=1.40.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.ContentReference com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.IOContext.contentReference()'
    at deployment.psMobileServerAdminConsole-${acp.version}.war//com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.FromXmlParser.<init>(FromXmlParser.java:263)
    at deployment.psMobileServerAdminConsole-${acp.version}.war//com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:653)
    at deployment.psMobileServerAdminConsole-${acp.version}.war//com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:30)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core@2.12.6//com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.12.6.1//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3643)
```

The odd thing is that I do not import these 2.12.6 dependencies explicitly or in transitive way - I only use 2.15.2

[Jackson dependencies screenshot from IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgM9d.png)

Full dependency tree: https://github.com/lrd2/working/blob/main/dependency_tree.txt

So any idea what causes the conflict and how to resolve it?

Comment: Are your jackson dependencies imported with a version defined? What if you try to delete a version from dependency definition so that it could come from BOM?

Comment: @VitalyChura it doesn't seem to work. I deleted some versions of explicitly imported jackson dependencies, but they were not downloaded based on azure-sdk-bom dependency management. Is this the way I should implement it, or add another BOM?

Comment: How are you deploying this? I see something related to war in the stacktrace. If you create a war file and your server provides a version of a library that might take precedence over the one from the application (depending on the rules and configuration of the server).

Comment: @M.Deinum correct, I deploy a war to Wildfly server. I can see that it indeed uses jackson dependencies, all 2.16.2 version :/

Comment: @M.Deinum bingo, I changed some dependencies in my wildfly configuration. The application no longer uses these "2.16.2" and azure blob SDK finally manages to create a container. THANK YOU

Comment: I'm not to familiar with WilfFly but couldn't you just specify that you want to give the ones from the application precedence? You can do this in WebSphere as well with APPLICATION_FIRST/PARENT_LAST classloading, it simply changes the order in which classes are loaded/detected.

Answer (score 0):

It was a WildFly server, to which I deployed the application, that caused the problem. It was overriding jackson dependencies configured in the app with predefined ones. After replacing them in WildFly configuration, the problem disappeared and the Azure SDK creates the blob container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).